# WebStorm: Throwing error code 32708 when pushing Git branch

Tags: git, webstorm

I have noticed that when pushing a Git branch to my private GitHub account, my installation of WebStorm on Ubuntu (see particulars below) will show the "Pushing" message for about two minutes, then ask for the SSH passkey - although the "Remember" checkbox is always checked. Once I enter the pass key, the push goes through successfully.

When looking at the idea.log, I noticed the following:

> ERROR - redentialStore.CredentialStore - secret_password_store_sync error code 32708, error message null
>
> java.lang.Throwable: secret_password_store_sync error code 32708, error message null
>
> ... rest of stack trace

It would appear that this would explain the delays in pushing, and the asking of the passkey after a few minutes.

I am trying to determine how to fix the problem, and with that I need some guidance. I assume that I can simply issue a new pass key, but I feel that trying to fix issues without understanding the problem is Bad.

Here are the particulars:

- WebStorm 2018.1.4 Build #WS-181.5087.27
- JDK: 1.8.0_152-release
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Comment: What option do you have selected at `Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords`. Most likely "Keychain". Switch to "KeePass" (you may need to re-enter any logins/password though)

Comment: Other than that it's similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185926 -- no known reasons why it's happening and how to resolve it (while keeping Keychain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestions given by LazyOne did indeed fix the problem.

Here is what I did:

- In Webstorm, went to Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords
- Changed the selection from "in native Keychain" to "in KeePass".
- Apply | Ok.
- Made a change, pushed the change. As expected, I was asked for the pass key. This time, however, it took just seconds.
- Made another change, did another push. As expected, Webstorm automatically applied the saved pass key.